# Intel Core 2 CPU

Tags: cpu, history

Was the Intel Core 2 the first Intel CPU to have multiple CPU cores?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No the Pentium Dual cores were, more specifically the Pentium D series processors. The [Intel Processor comparison utility](http://ark.intel.com/#desktopprocessors) show that the [Intel® Pentium® D Processor 805](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=27511&processor=805&spec-codes=SL8ZH) was released Q1 2005 and it was the first true Dual core consumer CPU released by intel (There were P4's that included hyper-threading). The first Core2 I could find was the [Core™2 Duo Processor E4300](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=28024&processor=E4300&spec-codes=SL9TB,SLA99) which released in Q3 2006.

Comment: I wonder why this article says different? Maybe the 805 was delayed in shipment?...http://www.zdnet.co.uk/reviews/cpus-desktop/2005/04/05/intels-first-dual-core-cpu-benchmarked-39193811/

Comment: Intel's History says the Pentium D was first. http://download.intel.com/pressroom/kits/IntelProcessorHistory.pdf

Comment: @Moab:  Because the media tend to be better reporters than researchers.  =D

Comment: Agree, they wanted to show off the flagship extreme edition rather than the lowly 805.

Comment: Don't forget Core Duo (not Core 2), out January 5 2006. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yonah_(microprocessor)

Comment: Good point @Joel the core duo and solo released before the core2.

Comment: Whether or not the Pentium D was a dual core CPU depends on your precise definition of "dual core". It was two physically distinct cores in the same package.